# array cannot be resolved to a variable. Anylogic

Tags: parameters, simulation, anylogic

I am working upon my thesis. For the first time I am working upon Any logic. I have only made a population agent named tasks and other agents which I require in my work. then I tried to build it but I get this error "Description: array cannot be resolved to a variable. Location: Thesis/Main/tasks - Tasks"
I have no idea what to do [a snapshot of my work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yeEGV.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in a way writing array in there is like writing these other options:

- banana
- the sky is pretty because it's blue
- alsjkdfasi348rsd

The special characteristics of all these 3 options, that are the same you have with the word "array" is that you have not defined what array is

YOu will not be able to progress with this model until you learn the very basics of java